# Exchange POST variables using CAMEL

Tags: java, apache-camel, esb

I'm building some type of ESB and one of things that my WSB have to do is to exchange data between two websites build in Spring.

The exchange should works like proxy, but adding some informations to the body of sended message.

To do this now, i was using cxf and jax-rs.

But i'm still thinking, is there any possibility to use some build in features in CAMEL.

The reason why i choosed cxf was, that CAMEL doesn't have any webservice, so i didn't known how to send **POST data** do CAMEL.

Maybe you have some experience in CAMEL and you know how to send data from **website/webservice** through HTTP or any other way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a Camel CXF proxy example you can take a look at: http://camel.apache.org/cxf-proxy-example.html

Comment: Ok, i found this example before, but i didn't concentrate over it. Now i downloaded this project and at the begining i builded it and copied to fuse-esb **deploy** folder. Next i've looked into **http://localhost:8181/cxf/** site, where i can see all my cxf projects and i didn't see it. Is this project should run as normal cxf project in Fuse-esb/servicemix or it will be set as a tomcat project? When i'm trying to open **http://localhost:8181/camel-example-cxf-proxy/webservices/incident** i get 404. Could you help me to run this project under Fuse-ESB ?